# What is Vue.extend for?

Tags: vue.js

This is a simple enough one, but I'm not getting the answer I need from the documentation. I'm in the process of learning Vue.js, and I don't really understand where Vue.extend fits in. I get Vue.component, but I don't see what [Vue.extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) does which [Vue.component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component) doesn't. Is it just a legacy feature from 1.0? If not, where is it useful in Vue 2.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709462/how-to-extend-a-vuejs-with-a-method

Answer (score 69):

Their guide in the previous Vuejs.org site had a document.

Copied from http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/composition.html which is forked from vuejs/Vuejs.org at version 0.10.6 of Vuejs.

> It is important to understand the difference between `Vue.extend()`
> and `Vue.component()`. Since `Vue` itself is a constructor,
> `Vue.extend()` is a **class inheritance method**. Its task is to
> create a sub-class of `Vue` and return the constructor.
> `Vue.component()`, on the other hand, is an **asset registration
> method** similar to `Vue.directive()` and `Vue.filter()`. Its task is
> to associate a given constructor with a string ID so Vue.js can pick
> it up in templates. When directly passing in options to
> `Vue.component()`, it calls `Vue.extend()` under the hood.
>
> Vue.js supports two different API paradigms: the class-based,
> imperative, Backbone style API, and the markup-based, declarative, Web
> Components style API. If you are confused, think about how you can
> create an image element with `new Image()`, or with an `<img>` tag.
> Each is useful in its own right and Vue.js tries to provide both for
> maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 40):

In addition to the answers provided, there is a practical use case for calling `Vue.extend()` directly if you are using TypeScript.

It is recommended in most cases to import component definitions from other files when they are needed, instead of registering them globally with `Vue.component()`. It keeps things organized in larger projects and makes it easier to trace problems.

With the right library, TypeScript can look at your component definition and figure out what the type of the component will be when it's initialized, meaning it can then check the functions you've defined to see if they make sense (i.e. if you reference `this.foo` there is actually a prop, data field, computed value, or method named `foo`). If you use `Vue.component()` it will be able to do this, but not if you use the other typical way of making components available, which is exporting object literals.

However, another option is to export your component definitions wrapped in `Vue.extend()`. TypeScript will then be able to recognize it as a Vue component and run its type checking accordingly, but you won't have to abandon the best-practice pattern of exporting components rather than registering them globally.

Comment: this is also useful when not using TS, but using an IDE which looks up type definitions for intellisense.

Comment: thank you. this is exactly what i was thinking but you explained it more clearly than the documentation.

Comment: I was struggling with this for hours when Typescript was complaining about `this.$refs` and I couldn't figure it out why. Wrapping my plain object with `Vue.extend({ ..... })` solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks @mattias-martens your final paragraph about TS and what `Vue.extend` does helped me understand what I was missing about why it solved all my type errors when trying to access `$vuetify` or `$store` or `$route` in a nuxt+ts+vuetify project.

I Was able to solve it with `Vue.extend` but did not see clear explenation in the docs to why this is the way to go. So thanks. Maybe this will help more people in the future here

Answer (score 39):

The documentation for Vue v2 is a bit sparse on `Vue.extends` but in short:

You use [`Vue.extend`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) to create component *definition* (called "component constructor" in old documentation) and [`Vue.component`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component) to [register](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Registration) it so it can be used in template to actually create component *instance*.

```html
<div id="example">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

```js
// define
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})
// register
Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)
// create a root instance
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

However, everywhere in Vue API where you can pass "component constructor" created by `Vue.extend` you can pass plain object instead and it will call `Vue.extend` [for you](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Registration-Sugar).

So the previous example can be written as

```js
// define
var MyComponent = {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
}
// register
Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)
// create a root instance
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

It seams that people now prefer to define components just as plain JS object (called *options object* in Vue world).

You can see that in current documentation for Vue v2 you rarely see `Vue.extends` mentioned while in docs for v1 it is clearly explained in one of the first chapters that describes [Vue Instance](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html) (compare it with [v2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)) and very well explained in [Components](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html) chapter. It is explicitly stated that passing options object directly is just a [sugar](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Registration-Sugar).

My guess is, to keep it simple and easier to learn, the new documentation just use plain objects everywhere. Why explain additional concept like "Vue constructor function", "component constructor" and what is `Vue.extend` when 99% of time you don't need to understand it? You can define all your app's components with plain JS options objects and [register](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) them without using `Vue.extends`. The only place when you must use vue constructor function is when creating *root Vue instance* with `new Vue({...})`. This uses base `Vue` constructor function. You don't need to know that *Vue constructor can be extended to create reusable component constructors with pre-defined options* because *although you can create extended instances imperatively, in most cases you will be registering a component constructor as a custom element and composing them in templates declaratively.*([source](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Constructor))

So documentation authors decided you don't need to learn about `Vue.extends`. But are there any use case where it's worth to use `Vue.extend` instead of plain *options* object?

Yes.

### Typescript

If you want to use Typescript (and don't like [class-style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components) components) then to have proper type inference you [should](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage) use `Vue.extend` instead of plain objects. It uses [`ThisType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141) to get proper inference for `this` object.

[image: image showing code with Vue.extend function where we see it's recognized by Typescript]

### Component inheritance (and Typescript again)

You can use `.extend` not only on base `Vue` constructor function, but also on your custom component. This is less flexible than [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) because you can use many mixins in component and `.extend` approach works just with one component. However, it works better with Typescript for which mixins seems to [not play well](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-mixins-with-typescript/24256/8). With `.extend` Typescript support is probably "good enough" for many cases. You can access fields from inherited component but if your component have some names collision with "base" component then it doesn't work well (for example I get a type of `never` for conflicting props' names).

```html
<div id="appBar">
    {{fooMessage}} || {{barMessage}} || {{ additionalData}}
    <button v-on:click="changeAllMessages">Change</button>
</div>
```

```js
var FooComponent = Vue.extend({
    data: () => ({
        fooMessage: 'Foo message'
    }),
    methods: {
        changeFooMessage() {
            this.fooMessage = "Foo message changed";
        }
    }
})
var BarComponent = FooComponent.extend({
    data: () => ({
        barMessage: "Bar message",
    }),
    methods: {
        changeAllMessages() {
            this.barMessage = "Bar message changes";
            this.changeFooMessage();
        }
    }
});
new BarComponent({ el: "#appBar", data: { additionalData: "additional data passed" } });
```

Here I also showed that you can use you custom component to create *root Vue instance* (`new BarComponent({...})`). Same like you can do with `new Vue({...})`. Maybe it's not that useful but it shows that  `BarComponent` and `FooComponent` are just *extended* base `Vue` constructor functions and you can use it the same way as you would use `Vue`.

Comment: Oh, this is good to know that you can use Vue.extend for subclassing components!
Thanks for this explanation!

Answer (score 33):

I think the confusion is because extend & component are closely connected. To create a component Vue calls extend internally:

```
// register an options object (automatically call Vue.extend)
Vue.component('my-component', { /* ... */ })
```

Therefore you can use extend to mount a subclass of the base Vue constructor (a component constructor): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend

However you are unlikely to come across or need to go down this road. Instead you'll be using components to get named subclasses which you can easily reference within your application.

Therefore Extend isn't really a "legacy" feature, it is central to Vue components, but the added sugar that components provide make them the default way you'll be working.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to understand Vue.extend is that it creates an object that extends the Vue class.

Typically, to create a new instance of Vue,

```
var vm = new Vue( {/* ...*/})
```

Vue.extend also creates an instance of Vue ie

```
var page = Vue.extend ({ /* ... */});
```

page is as much an instance of Vue as `vm` above.

To mount page, you have to mount it on a div ie,

```
new page().$mount('#page-div')
```

Where `#page-div` is is the I'd of a div in your page

Also, to programmers with knowledge of object oriented programming, let's say

```
var ext = Vue.extend({/ *...* /})
```

Then we can interpret ext as

```
class ext extends Vue{

}
```

Note that when you create a component, ie `Vue.component('my-component', {  /* ... */  })`, It actually does the following : `Vue.component('my-component', Vue.extend({ /* ... */}))`, thus Vue.component calls Vue.extend under the hood.

If you're still confused, think of `Vue.extend` as an utility function for creating components