# Vue, TypeScript Can't Call Component Methods

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm still pretty new to Vue and I'm having troubles working this out. From all the code examples I can find, my code looks like it should work.

I have defined a component like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="site-header">
            <img v-bind:src="headerImgUrl" alt="hero-image">
            <div class="hero-text strokeme">Some Hero Text</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    const bgimages = [
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero1.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero2.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero3.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero4.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero5.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero6.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero7.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero8.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero9.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero10.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero11.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero12.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero13.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero14.png') },
    ];

    @Component({
        data() {
            console.log(this.getHeaderImageUrl());
            return {
                headerImgUrl: bgimages[0].url,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getHeaderImageUrl(): string {
                const min = Math.ceil(1);
                const max = Math.floor(14);
                const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                return bgimages[i].url;
            },
        },
    })
    export default class Home extends Vue { }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    #site-header {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .hero-text {
        font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size: 6em;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000;
    }
    .strokeme {
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff;
    }
</style>
```

However, when compiling I get the error:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'getHeaderImageUrl' does not exist on type
>   'Vue'.

How can I set this up so it can call it's own methods?  Also is there a better approach to get a random url into an image source?

Alternatively, how would I update the `data.headerImgUrl` from inside the `getHeaderImageUrl()` method?

If I try this:

```
methods: {
    getHeaderImageUrl() {
        const min = Math.ceil(1);
        const max = Math.floor(14);
        const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        //return bgimages[i].url;
        this.headerImgUrl = bgimages[i].url;
    },
},
```

It errors with:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'headerImgUrl' does not exist on type
>   'Vue'.

I'm clearly still not getting the scoping on something or have configured something wrong as this seem to be really basic stuff.

**UPDATE**

So I've re-written my component like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="site-header">
            <img v-bind:src="headerImgUrl" alt="hero-image">
            <div class="hero-text strokeme">Some Hero Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    const bgimages = [
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero1.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero2.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero3.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero4.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero5.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero6.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero7.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero8.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero9.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero10.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero11.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero12.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero13.png') },
        { url: require('../assets/hero/hero14.png') },
    ];

    export default Vue.extend({
        computed: {
            headerImgUrl() {
                return this.getHeaderImageUrl();
            },
        },
        methods: {
            getHeaderImageUrl() {
                const min = Math.ceil(1);
                const max = Math.floor(14);
                const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                console.log(1);
                return bgimages[i].url;
            },
        },
    });

</script>

<style lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

But I'm still getting an error where the method is inaccessible:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'getHeaderImageUrl' does not exist on type
>   'CombinedVueInstance>>'.

Comment: I had quite a lot of issue using the Class-style vue components, so I just always opted to use the `Vue.extend({/*definitions here*/})`

Comment: Really? How would I re-write this into that format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually combining two different approaches to create a component.
Here are two examples:

using "vue-property-decorator" :

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component()
export default class HelloDecorator extends Vue {

    @Prop(type: String, default: "")
    name: string;

    @Prop({ type: Number, default: 1 })
    initialEnthusiasm: number;

    enthusiasm = this.initialEnthusiasm;

    increment() {
        this.enthusiasm++;
    }

    decrement() {
        this.enthusiasm--;
    }

    get exclamationMarks(): string {
        return Array(this.enthusiasm + 1).join('!');
    }
}
```

using extend :

```js
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        enthusiasmLevel: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }
    },
    computed: {
        helloMessage() {
            return "Hello " + this.name + this.getExclamationMarks(this.enthusiasmLevel);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getExclamationMarks(numChars) {
            return Array(numChars + 1).join('!');
        },
        onDecrement() {
            this.$emit("onDecrement");
        },
        onIncrement() {
            this.$emit("onIncrement");
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow, OK. So how does `Vue.component('', {})` really differ?

Comment: I've refactored to use the `.extend` approach but when I try to set `headerImgUrl` it's now read-only.

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow answer about the difference between extend and component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719200/what-is-vue-extend-for

Comment: for readonly purpose you can create a getter and a private field of headerImgUrl

Comment: No, the problem is the other way around it seems to be readonly when I want read/write. I'm getting a false positive with a typescript error but the app runs ok so I need to investigate my environment I think.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got to my solution. The app worked but TS Linter was throwing a type wobble. I fixed by specifying the type explicitly like `headerImgUrl(): string`