# Is there any performance trade off of using Vue.extend() vs straight export?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In context of switching to typescript it appears to require

```
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend( { } )
```

instead of just
`export default { }`

There is some commentary here about the concept:
[What is Vue.extend for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719200/what-is-vue-extend-for)

But it still doesn't quite make sense.

For example, I am already calling `component()` either through the router

```
const routes = routerOptions.map(route => {
 return {
.....
    component: () => import(`@/components/${route.component}.vue`)

.....
```

Or as `Vue.component('foo', foo)`

- So specifically I am trying to understand, if it's correct it has to be called "twice" (once directly, and once through subsequent calls to `component()`) what is the performance impact?
- And if there is no performance impact then why does typescript really need it?

Comment: TypeScript usually has little to nothing to do with performance. The TS code persists only until compilation, then it's stripped and replaced with pure JavaScript. So, TS code never really exists at runtime which is where performance comes into play.

Comment: My focus is on the Vue JS code being added